# Laravel Ignore not working for unique validation rule

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-9, laravel-request, laravel-data

I'm working on a simple API using Laravel. At the moment working on the update endpoint for my `categories` resource. A `name` for a `category` must be unique and that seems to be working just fine, but when performing an update it is failing even though I'm using `ignore`.

Here's my controller method:

```
public function update(
        UpdateCategoryRequest $request,
        CategoryData $data) : CategoriesResource
    {
        $category = UpsertCategoryAction::execute($data, $request);
        return new CategoriesResource($category);
    }
```

Here's my `execute` method in `UpsertCategoryAction`:

```
public static function execute(
        CategoryData $categoryData,
        Request $request) : Category
    {
        return Category::updateOrCreate(
            [
                'id' => $categoryData->id,
            ],
            [
                ...$categoryData->all()
            ]
        );
    }
```

and finally here's my validation rules which are declared on my DTO (I'm using spatie's laraveldata package):

```
<?php

namespace Domain\Category\DataTransferObjects;

use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Spatie\LaravelData\Data;
/**
 * DTO to represent a Category
 */
class CategoryData extends Data
{
    public function __construct(
        public readonly ?int $id,
        public readonly string $name,
        public readonly int $parent,
        public readonly ?string $description,
        public readonly ?string $image
    ){}

    public static function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                Rule::unique('categories', 'name')
                    ->ignore(request('category'))
            ],
            'parent' => ['required', 'integer', 'gte:0'],
            'description' => ['nullable', 'sometimes', 'string'],
            'image' => ['nullable', 'sometimes', 'string'],
        ];
    }

}
```

As you can see, `name` is required and unique but should be ignored for an update. I'm using `request('category')` since this is a static method and I have no access to `$this`. Yes, I've confirmed already and `request('category')` is returning the correct id for the request.

When I try `PUT categories/5` for instance, with the following body:

```
{
    "name": "Winnifred Funk DDS",
    "parent": 1,
    "description": "Sit debitis necessitatibus quam. Molestiae voluptas sit at qui atque provident id. Animi et qui veritatis veniam laborum facilis. Rerum occaecati quasi ut hic nam dolor aspernatur.",
    "image": "875e2438e3ae806bd14c16adaf5155c5.jpg"
}
```

In which the only field updated was `parent`, I'm getting the following response:

```
{
    "message": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'Winnifred Funk DDS' for key 'categories.categories_name_unique' (SQL: insert into `categories` (`name`, `parent`, `description`, `image`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Winnifred Funk DDS, 1, Sit debitis necessitatibus quam. Molestiae voluptas sit at qui atque provident id. Animi et qui veritatis veniam laborum facilis. Rerum occaecati quasi ut hic nam dolor aspernatur., 875e2438e3ae806bd14c16adaf5155c5.jpg, 2022-08-10 11:47:52, 2022-08-10 11:47:52))",
    "exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
    "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
    "line": 759,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
            "line": 719,
            "function": "runQueryCallback",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
            "line": 545,
            "function": "run",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
            "line": 497,
            "function": "statement",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Processors/Processor.php",
            "line": 32,
            "function": "insert",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php",
            "line": 3246,
            "function": "processInsertGetId",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Processors\\Processor",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php",
            "line": 1834,
            "function": "insertGetId",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php",
            "line": 1220,
            "function": "__call",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php",
            "line": 1185,
            "function": "insertAndSetId",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php",
            "line": 1026,
            "function": "performInsert",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php",
            "line": 568,
            "function": "save",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php",
            "line": 302,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php",
            "line": 569,
            "function": "tap"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php",
            "line": 23,
            "function": "updateOrCreate",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php",
            "line": 2176,
            "function": "forwardCallTo",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php",
            "line": 2188,
            "function": "__call",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/src/Domain/Category/Actions/UpsertCategoryAction.php",
            "line": 20,
            "function": "__callStatic",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "::"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/app/Http/Controllers/API/CategoriesController.php",
            "line": 67,
            "function": "execute",
            "class": "Domain\\Category\\Actions\\UpsertCategoryAction",
            "type": "::"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php",
            "line": 54,
            "function": "update",
            "class": "App\\Http\\Controllers\\API\\CategoriesController",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php",
            "line": 45,
            "function": "callAction",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
            "line": 261,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
            "line": 204,
            "function": "runController",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 725,
            "function": "run",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 141,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php",
            "line": 50,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php",
            "line": 126,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php",
            "line": 102,
            "function": "handleRequest",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php",
            "line": 54,
            "function": "handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/sanctum/src/Http/Middleware/EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful.php",
            "line": 33,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 141,
            "function": "Laravel\\Sanctum\\Http\\Middleware\\{closure}",
            "class": "Laravel\\Sanctum\\Http\\Middleware\\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 116,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/sanctum/src/Http/Middleware/EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful.php",
            "line": 34,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Laravel\\Sanctum\\Http\\Middleware\\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 116,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 726,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 703,
            "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 667,
            "function": "runRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 656,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 141,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php",
            "line": 31,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php",
            "line": 40,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php",
            "line": 86,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php",
            "line": 62,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php",
            "line": 39,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 116,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 142,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 111,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/public/index.php",
            "line": 52,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/resources/server.php",
            "line": 16,
            "function": "require_once"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: First, i think it should be `$request->all()`, i don't see where you retrieve the data from the request

Comment: no it should not. again, this is a static method. The data is injected through the DTO package. The issue is not the data but the rule. I've updated the question with the complete DTO class

Comment: The rule is fine you have an error after the validation when it tries to insert it in database, the issue is when you call updateOrCreate, try to dump the arguments, there is something wrong, perhaps `$categoryData->id` is null or something

Comment: You confirmed that `request('category')` returns the correct data for the request but your request body you shared doesn't seem to be including the category id in it

Comment: @apokryfos `request('category')` returns the id of the resource i'm trying to update

Comment: You mean inside the static method you shared if you do `dd(request('category'))` you get the right value?

Comment: yes @apokryfos, when I add `dd(request('category'));` within `rules` I'm getting 1 which is the id of my request

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Your problem is not validation you seem to be inserting a new category with the same name rather than updating the existing category.

Comment: oh wow, that seems to be the case! but can't see why this is happening, I'm running a PUT request from my REST client and in my Action i'm using `updateOrCreate`. One thing, how did you catch that?

Comment: I fixed it. Had to include `id` in my body request which doesn't feel right. But anyway, I can get it from the request and do the assignment in code instead of passing it via the request body. Thanks. If you want add your comment as an answer so can mark it as the right answer

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue I solved it with the following Rule facade change:

```
Rule::unique('categories')->ignore(request('category'), 'id')
```

Comment: so I just updated it to be `Rule::unique('categories', 'name')
                    ->ignore(request('category'), 'id')` but nothing changed, still getting the same error

Comment: Then I hope this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198897/laravel-check-for-unique-rule-without-itself-in-update