# Email Unique Validation

Tags: php, laravel

My problem is updating User profile!
For example, as a user with ID "1",  request is sent to the server for an update
If user send a new email address to the server , update will be  done! , but if user  send the current e-mail address ( in database exists), The Server should not do the update!,
Also, consider the user with ID number 2, but this time, if user with id 2  .accidentally has send email address of user 1, server  doesn't  update the email address and  return  to the user this  validation error :
"This email has already been Taken by another user"

i'm tying to make best validation role for Profile's Table

Profile Request :

```
public function rules()
{
    return[
        "avatar_src"=>"string",
        "address"=>"string",
        'email' => Rule::unique('profiles')->ignore($this->user()->id),
    ];
}
```

**I have written this, but I'm facing this error in any case!**

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "email": [
            "The email has already been taken."
        ]
    }
}
```

this is my database Structure :

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 4 validation email unique constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28144724/laravel-4-validation-email-unique-constraint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write custom validation for that

```
public function rules()
{
    return[
        "avatar_src"=>"string",
        "address"=>"string",
        'email' => function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
        
        if(isset($this->user()->id)&&!empty($this->user()->id)){
            
            $profile=Profile::where('email',$value)->where('user_id','!=',$this->user()->id)->first();
            
            if($profile){
             $fail('The '.$attribute.' is invalid.');
            }
            
        }
           
        },
    ];
}
```

**Updated**

```
public function rules()
{
    return[
        "avatar_src"=>"string",
        "address"=>"string",
        'email' =>["email", function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {

            if(isset($this->user()->id)&&!empty($this->user()->id)){

                $profile=Profile::where('email',$value)->where('user_id','!=',$this->user()->id)->first();

                if($profile){
                    $fail('The '.$attribute.' is invalid.');
                }

            }

        }]
        ];
}
```

Comment: can you try this well 'email' => 'unique:profiles,user_id,'.$this->user()->id, once

Comment: how can i check Email  format is correct ?

Comment: email' =>['email', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) { }]

Comment: is this working ? 'email' => 'unique:profiles,user_id,'.$this->user()->id,

Comment: no didn't work .just  working  with function

Answer (score 0):

Your validation is Ok, you have to setup an "email verification process" and erase email field if verification does not succeed.