# How to pass the value inside the model for checking in the rules

Tags: php, validation, laravel, unique, laravel-validation

I am trying to have this rules in my model

```
'Email' =>  'email|unique:tablename,coloumntoignore,ignoreid',
```

The above rules is to check the unique coloumn except the id to be supplied in the `ignoreid`

I face two issues here

I am getting the user input

```
$DriverData = Input::except(array('_token'));
```

and sending it to the model

```
$validation  = Validator::make($DriverData, DriverModel::$updaterules);
```

Note : This update is not the self so i can't get it by `Auth::user()->id` and my primary key is not `id`

I check it by

```
'Email' =>  'email|unique:driver_details,email,4',
```

It told me error

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `driver_details` where `email` = allaudeen.s@gmail.coms and `id` <> 4)
```

though i mentioned the `protected $primaryKey = 'DriverId';`

**So, How can i have get the value of the field inside the model so that i should check for the rule to check the unique coloumn except its one**

Note : The dirty way like putting the DriverId in the session at controller and getting here like that is not preferred.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using resourceful routes/controller, the id of the record you're trying to update should be the parameter passed to the update method in the controller.

If you're not using resourceful routes/controller, then the id of the record you're updating needs to be passed in along with the other form data.

As for the validation rule, since your id field is not `id`, you need to tell the rule that. The fourth parameter to the unique rule is the name of the id field. Documentation on the unique rule is [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-unique).

```
'Email' =>  'email|unique:driver_details,email,4,DriverId',
```

Once you figure out how you're getting the id of the record you're updating, you will need to figure out how to inject that id into your email rule. Since it looks like your rules are defined as a static attribute on the `DriverModel`, you may want to take a look at this question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054979/laravel-4-form-validation-should-be-unique-on-update-form-but-not-if-current/28056267#28056267). Basically, you'll need a placeholder in your rule, and then a static method on the model that can replace the placeholder with your specified id:

```
class DriverModel extends Eloquent {
    public static $updaterules = array(
        'Email' => 'email|unique:driver_details,email,%1$s,DriverId'
    );
    public static function getUpdateRules($id = 'NULL') {
        $rules = self::$updaterules;
        $rules['Email'] = sprintf($rules['Email'], $id);
        return $rules;
    }
}

// usage
$validation  = Validator::make($DriverData, DriverModel::getUpdateRules($id));
```

Comment: Thanks i overcome the `'Email' =>  'email|unique:driver_details,email,4,DriverId',` But even i use the getUpdateRule while i use the `$validation  = Validator::make($DriverData, DriverModel::getUpdateRules($id));` in the controller i am getting the `Undefined variable: getUpdateRules` error

Comment: You probably have a typo.  Make sure you're using `DriverModel::getUpdateRules($id)` and not `DriverModel::$getUpdateRules($id)`. There should be no `$` in front of the function.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
'email' => 'unique:table,email_column_to_check,id_to_ignore'
replace segments table, email_column_to_check, id_to_ignore in above example
```

reference :  http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-unique